# socket.error: [Errno 10013] Port forbidden access permissions

Tags: port, sockets

When trying to use a Python script I get this error:

> socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in
>   a way forbidden by its access permissions

I put the post on Stackoverflow and I have been guided to come here and follow up with why I get the error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370235/socket-error-sending-email-using-gmail

As the post on stackoverflow suggests, the issue is not with Python, but my computer. I can even telnet to smtp.gmail.com

Can anyone provide any suggestions?

EDIT: SOLVED

The problem was McAfee Antivirus. It was blocking the socket connection.

From McAfee Access Protection Log

23/08/2013  10:23:54 a.m.   Blocked by port blocking rule   C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\python.exe  Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail 74.125.25.108:25

I disabled McAfee completely and it worked fine after that.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using. Maybe you need to open firewall or router ports.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I think I found it. I tried disabling McAfee, but it still logs it in the log file
23/08/2013 10:23:54 a.m. Blocked by port blocking rule  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\python.exe Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail 74.125.25.108:25.

Comment: Great, please make an answer post so that other who run into this problem can easily find the solution :)

Comment: McAfee's warning comes from a good thought, be careful writing code like this :)

Comment: the port is may be already taken , so change the port.

Comment: I got the same puzzling socket error, but in my case McAfee was blocking any attempt to connect to port 6668 (even a single connection on the loopback). From the AccessProtectionLog.txt: `Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent IRC communication 127.0.0.1:6668`.

Answer (score 0):

VirusScan Console->Access Protection->Anti-Virus Standard protection->Prevent mass-mailing worms from sending mails (uncheck  from Block tab)